# Cannot get DataTable to load all data

Tags: jquery, datatables

Something seems to be wrong with the data, because I'm getting the `Requested unknown parameter 2 for row 0` when I execute the following:

```
var items = $('#items').DataTable({
        dom: "<'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>",
        paginationType: "full_numbers",
        language: {
            lengthMenu: "_MENU_ items per page"
        },
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        stateSave: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "items/data",
            method: 'post'
        },
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: ['th-image'],
                searchable: false,
                data: 'image_url',
                render: function (data, type, full) {
                    return '<img src="' + data + '" alt="thumbnail" class="img-thumbnail" />';
                }
            },
            {
                targets: ['th-manufacturer'],
                data: 'manufacturer',
                render: function (data, type, full) {
                    var manufacturer = data.substring(0, 40);

                    if (data.length > 40)
                        manufacturer += '...';

                    return manufacturer;
                }
            },
            {
                targets: ['th-title'],
                data: 'title',
                render: function (data, type, full) {
                    var title = data.substring(0, 40);

                    if (data.length > 40)
                        title += '...';

                    return title;
                }
            },
            {
                targets: ['th-actions'],
                data: 'actions',
                searchable: false,
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                targets: ['th-id'],
                data: 'id',
                searchable: true,
                visible: false
            }
        ]
    });
```

On this table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="items">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="th-image">Image</th>
        <th class="th-manufacturer">Manufacturer</th>
        <th class="th-mpn">MPN</th>
        <th class="th-upc">UPC</th>
        <th class="th-title">Title</th>
        <th class="th-actions">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

The fields `image`, `manufacturer`, `title` and `actions` all show up correctly, but `mpn` and `upc` are empty despite having values in the server data response.

I've created DataTables like this before using this same sort of initialization values without the need for a `columns` value, so I'm likely missing something obvious, but I have yet to find it.

DataTables 1.10.7.

Comment: columnDefs don't show properties `mpn and upc`

Comment: I thought columnDefs only needed to have non-default definitions and the rest were auto-picked up according to order of TH's and data array index. Have done it this way in previous setups. Have things changed?

Comment: definitely works that way when data is simple array ... I could be wrong but I think when data is array's of objects you need to add the definition so plugin knows what property. Remember that objects don't have order

Comment: That appears to have been it. Dumped an array of data settings into the `columns` element of the initial config and it all loaded up. Had to set string based `targets` for each of them though.

Comment: can you provide the response of ajax: {
            url: "items/data",
            method: 'post'
        } so i can check the array values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're returning an array of objects you need to define all columns data with either `columns` or `columnDefs` options. From the [manual](https://datatables.net/manual/data):

> The down side of using objects is that you need to explicitly tell DataTables which property it should use from the object for each column. This is done using the `columns.data` and / or `columns.render` options.

Add definitions for `mpn` and `upc` data properties to `columnDefs` as shown below to resolve the problem.

```
        {
            targets: ['th-mpn'],
            data: 'mpn'
        },
        {
            targets: ['th-upc'],
            data: 'upc'
        },
```